# grep command to display same word with different spellings

Tags: grep, search

I created one table of employees.

```
    1 Andy Account
    2 Grecie HR
    3 Jyorge Marketing
    4 Seeya HR
    5 Princy Account
    6 Siya Production
```

Here the names of 4th employee and 6th employee are same but spellings are different. So i want to display only that records using grep command. I tried it like:

```
grep S[iee]ya emp
```

and

```
grep S[[i][ee]]ya emp
```

but it didn't work.
Any solution?

Comment: you can also use `grep -e 'Seeya' -e 'Siya'` ... helps if you want to add `-F` option as well

Comment: You might also want to use the `-w` (whole word) option for this command.

Comment: to do this properly, you probably should use a language like perl or python that has a library implementing the [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) or similar algorithm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the OR operator '|' in grep:

```
grep -E 'S(i|ee)ya' emp
```

---

```
4 Seeya HR
6 Siya Production
```

Answer (score 10):

`[...]` creates a character class, not a group, you want to use a group that contains an `|` or operator

```
grep 'S\(ee\|i\)ya' emp
```

will do such a group and find those two lines.  You can also clean that up a bit by telling grep to use extended regex with `-E`, then you don't have to escape the characters to make them special

```
grep -E 'S(ee|i)ya' emp
```

Answer (score -2):

```
grep 'S.*ya'
```

seems to work also.  The `*` quantifier matches between zero and unlimited times.

Comment: Would this not possibly match some unwanted things?

Comment: Would also return `true` if the name is 'Shit ya'